# How to choose a specific Rudraksha?

Tags: shiva, rudraksha

The Rudraksha comes 14 different types. Each type has its own importance & benefits. If a person wants to have Rudraksha for him/her then which Rudraksha should he/she Dharan (take)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a secret relationship between Rudraksha and the wearer, which is very secret and can not be shared. Rudraksha tree was born from Lord Shiva's tears, so have great energy of healing others.

The wearer's nature is affected from rudraksha only. Different types of rudraksha have different effects. One can also wear combination of rudraksha.

**For Example**, if you fell nervous, Keep a big size 5 Mukhi Rudraksha with you. Whenever you feel nervous due to sudden shock and feel cold, just hold it tight in your right palm for ten minutes. You will regain your confidence and body will start warming up.

The number of faces a bead can have varies from a single face up to 21 faces. They are used for different purposes, so it would be improper to just buy something in the shop and put it on the body. Wearing the wrong type could disturb one’s life.

### Ek mukhi

> A lot of people want to wear an ek mukhi, which has only one face because it is very powerful.
>
> People say if you wear an ek mukhi, you will leave your family within twelve days. Whether you leave the family or not is not the issue, it is just that it will make your energies in such a way that you will want to be alone. It doesn't make you compatible to be with other people
>
> In Shiva puran, all types are mentioned of rudraksha, in which ek mukhi is shiva himself, which can destroy any worst sin. [Read last paragraph about Shiva puran Rudraksha here](http://www.shivshankar.in/worship-method-of-siva-lingas/).

### Five-faced

> Five-faced beads or panchmukhi is safe and good for everyone – man, woman and child. It is for general wellbeing, health and freedom. It lowers your blood pressure, calms your nerves and brings a certain calmness and alertness in your nervous system.

### Six-faced

> Children below 12 years of age can wear six-faced beads. It will help them calm down and be more focused. Above all they will receive the right type of attention from the adult.
>
> many are there, you can find on [internet](http://blog.ishafoundation.org/yoga-meditation/the-significance-of-rudraksh/)

### Astrology

> As per the modern Astrologers; *Rudraksha* is used for removing malefic planetary effect. There are twenty seven Constellations. Each has control of one of the Nine Planets. Each constellation is controlled by some related *Rudraksha*. Therefore according to these constellations, various multifaceted *Rudraksha* are worn (Control planets) and is found useful in multi-discipline.

### Ayurveda

> As per Ayurveda, Rudraksha strengthens the body constitutions. It removes the blood impurities and strengthens the body substance. It removes the bacteria inside as well as outside the Human Body. Rudraksha removes the headache, cough, paralysis, and blood pressure, heart disease and maternity problems. Wearing of Rudraksha brings glow on the face, which results in calm and charming personality.

But for some skins, it cause allergy, so better to wear what suits to your skin.

A person can take advice from any Hindu astrologer with his kundali can can ask him to suggest him any rudraksha type.

In my opinion

> Better to ask a person who has knowledge about it instead of just experimenting.

[If you want to choose rudraksha by yourself Please see this](http://www.rudraksham.com/choosing-rudraksha).

Comment: yes, precautions are required. You should be pious before touching it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the **[Devi Bhagwat Puran](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57385.html)** section on Rudraksh related discussion between Lord Shiva and his son Kartikeya, each different type has a different purpose:

> **One-faced Rudrākṣa reveals Paratattva (the highest Tattva)**; when worn, the knowledge of the highest Tattva arises; the Brahmā is seen then.

> **The two-faced Rudrākṣam** is Ardhanārīśvara, the Lord of the other half which represents women (in the same person); **if worn, Ardhanārīsvara Śiva is always pleased with that man who holds it.**

> The three-faced Rudrākṣam is Fire made manifest; it destroys in a moment the **sin of killing a woman**. The three-faced Rudrākṣam is the three Agnis, Dakṣiṇāgni, Gārhapatya, and Āhavaniya; **Bhagavān Agni is always pleased with that man who wears the three-faced Rudrākṣam.**

> The four-faced Rudrākṣam is Brahmā Himself. **The wearer gets his prosperity enhanced, his diseases destroyed, the divine knowledge springs in him and his heart is always pleased.**

> The five-faced Rudrākṣam is the five faced Śiva Himself; **Mahādeva gets pleased with him who holds it.**

> The Presiding Deity of the six faced Rudrākṣam is Kārtikeya. Some Pundits take Gaṇapati to be the Presiding Deity of the six-faced Rudrākṣam.

> The presiding Deity of the seven-faced Rudrākṣam is the seven Mātrikās, the Sun and the seven Ṛṣis. By putting on this, the **prosperity is increased, health and the pure knowledge are established. It should be put on when one becomes pure.**

> The Presiding Deity of the eight-faced Rudrākṣam is Brāhmī, the eight Mātrikās. **By holding this, the eight Vasus are pleased and the river Ganges is also pleased. The putting on of this makes the Jīvas truthful and pleasant-minded.**

> **The Devatā of the nine-faced Rudrākṣam is Yama; holding this puts off the fears of Death.**

> The Devatā of the ten-faced Rudrākṣam is ten quarters, **the ten quarters are pleased with him who wears the ten-faced Rudrākṣam.**

> The Devata of the eleven mouthed Rudrākṣam is the eleven Rudrās and Indra. **Holding this enhances happiness.**

> The twelve-faced Rudrākṣam is Viṣṇu made manifest; its Devatās are the twelve Ādityas; the devotees of Śiva should hold this.

> The thirteen-faced Rudrākṣam, if worn, **enables one to secure one’s desires; he does nowhere experience failures. The Kāma Deva becomes pleased with him who wears this.**

> **The fourteen-faced Rudrākṣam destroys all diseases and gives eternal health.**

So the choice of which one to wear by any particular person would depend on what the wearer wants to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important questions before buying a Rudraksha is “What Rudraksha Should I Wear?” and it is often challenging to identify the best Rudraksha for you. While there are several resources online, finding the Rudraksha that meets your requirement might be overwhelming.

Here is a simple guide that anyone can use for selecting their Rudraksha.

**Selecting Rudraksha Using Birth-Chart**
One of the most popular and widely used methods of selecting a Rudraksha is through the use of Vedic Birth Charts. A birth chart is a document that describes the position of the planets and all the astrological aspects that are used by Vedic Astrologers to study the personality, destiny, and potential weaknesses of an individual.

For [More information refer to this site.](https://nepalirudraksha.com/blogs/blog/rudraksha-for-beginners)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).