# Is there a name for a wrist mālā?

Tags: shiva, rudraksha, japamala

Is it called just *mālā*, or does it have a special name? I'm not concerned about the material, rather about the fact that it's shorter and worn on a wrist.

[image: Rudraksha beads]
[image: Wrist mala]

Comment: Yes.This is called **RUDRAKSHA MALA**.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Sorry, I wasn't clear in my question. I'm concerned about the fact that it's shorter and worn on a wrist, not about the material.

Comment: Yes. You can do that. But,now a days no one does that except saints who seek ultimate Truth. Lord Shiva wears it on wrist but you should take utmost precautions while you [select Rudraksha](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2698/3500), I suggest you to ask a priest in nearby Shiva Temple.

Comment: bracelet mala? I'm not sure. Traditionally, a full length mala is just rotated several times over the wrist.

Comment: The one in the image is not arudraksha mala.

Comment: @Rickross because someone edited three question and put a wrong image there. I'll fix that.

Comment: @PetrPudlák, I edited the answer to reflect the specific notion that the mala has to worn on wrist. The image you embedded doesn't emphasize the fact and hence, you are getting the same answer '*rudraksha*' every time.

Answer (score 2):

Shiva Purana, 1.25. 29 (The greatness of Rudrākṣa)

> śatamekottaraṃ kaṃṭhe bāhvorvai rudra saṃkhyayā | kūrparadvārayostatra ᴍᴀɴ̣ɪʙᴀᴍ̣ᴅʜᴇ tathā punaḥ || 29 ||
>
> "Hundred and one Rudrākṣas shall be worn round the neck; eleven Rudrāksas shall be worn round each of the arms, elbows and wrists."

1.25.33:

> "This is the rule regarding eleven hundred Rudrākṣas. If so many are not available, another auspicious procedure I mention to you."

Shiva Purana 1.25.34,35:

> śikhāyāmekarudrā kṣaṃ śirasā triṃśataṃ vahet  |
> paṃcāśacca gale dadhyādbāhvoḥ ṣoḍaśa ṣoḍaśa|| **ᴍᴀɴ̣ɪʙᴀᴍ̣ᴅʜᴇ dvādaśa** ||
>
> One Rudrākṣa shall be worn on the tuft, thirty on the head, fifty round the neck; sixteen in each of the arms; **twelve round each of the wrists**; Shiva Purana

That on the wrist is called as  **"ᴍᴀɴ̣ɪʙᴀɴᴅʜᴀɴᴀ"**

But also one who takes a Vow to wear it are supposed to refrain from :-

> madyaṃ māṃsaṃ tu laśunaṃ palāṇḍuṃ śigrumeva ca |
> śleṣmāṃtakaṃ viḍvarāhaṃ bhakṣaṇe varjayettataḥ || 1.25.43
>
> ”A devotee of Śiva shall refrain from eating meat, garlic, onion, red garlic, potherb, Śleṣmātaka, pig of rubbish and liquors."

Answer (score 0):

Its called Rudraksha beads (Mala). Rudraksha is used for prayer in Hinduism. The name rudraksha stems from Hindu mythology and means “the eyes of Shiva.” Size of beads are from 3 mm to 40 mm.

[image]

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I'm not concerned about the material (rudraksha). I'm interested if the shorter variant worn on a wrist has a specific name or not, probably it doesn't. In any case, thanks for the image, I've never seen the tree.